# Grails saved list not in dbconsole

Tags: grails

I am doing this:

```
class Face {
  String name
  def ears = []
  Nose nose

  void addEar(Ear ear){
    ears << ear
  }
}

class Nose {
  String name
}

class Ear {
  String name
}
```

And on Bootstrap.groovy:

```
  def nose = new Nose(name: "Nose")
  nose.save()

  def leftEar = new Ear(name: "Left ear")
  leftEar.save()
  def rightEar = new Ear(name: "Right ear")
  rightEar.save()

  def face = new Face(name: "Face", nose: nose)
  face.addEar(leftEar)
  face.addEar(rightEar)
  face.save()
```

When I run the app and enter dbconsole to see the tables, face has a reference to its nose and I can read its name "Face", but it has no reference to its ears. How should I save this list so I can access it later?

Or in case it's actually saved somewhere, where? How should I access it?

Comment: Take a look at Grails documentation about associations here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany (Focus on 'One to many' and 'Many to many' associations). You can find nice examples on how to declare association (static `hasMany` property) and add elements to them (`addTo*` method).

Comment: Awesome! I had tried to use hasMany but I didn't add elements with addTo, so it didn't work either. Now it works fine! Thank you! Would you answer the question so I can choose your answer as correct?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) I've just manually 'converted' my comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Grails documentation about associations](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany). Focus on 'One to many' and 'Many to many' associations. You can find nice examples on how to declare association (static `hasMany` property) and add elements to them (`addTo*` method).

Comment: All fields in a domain class that you want to be persistent must have a declared type, otherwise GORM has no idea how to store it and ignores it silently. The same would have happened if you stored a string/number/boolean/etc. in that property. This is used sometimes as a somewhat lazy way to have an intentionally transient/nonpersistent property, but my preference is to type it if that makes sense and then add it to the `transients` list to explicitly declare your intent.